# How to run macro from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in the workbook1 (code below).
I want to run this macro on another workbook, but it keeps opening the workbook1 and create the sheet in workbook1. It works fine if I copy the code into another workbook, but I want to run macro in another workbook from workbook1. The macro will create a sheet in workbook1 using another workbook data. How to make it create the sheet in an active workbook or another workbook.

```
Sub Pneumatic_Diagram()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim Machine As String
Dim iPnuematic As Integer
Dim iProject As Integer

Dim Lastrow As Long

Machine = Sheets("Project plan").Range("E4")
FileToOpen = "O:\060 Designs\06 All Pneumatic\Pneumatic_Tools\Pneumatic-Database2.xlsx"

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

'*** Delete define sheet name ***
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     If Sheet.Name = "Pnumatic_Diagram" Then
          Sheet.Delete
     End If
Next Sheet

'**** Copy GN. from Projectplan****
Sheets("Project plan").Range("B:B").Copy
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Follow up")).Name = "Pnumatic_Diagram"
Sheets("Pnumatic_Diagram").Range("L1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("L:L").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2).EntireRow.Delete
Range("L:L").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

'**** Get data from data base****

If FileToOpen <> False Then

    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    OpenBook.Sheets(Machine).Range("A:F").Copy
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pnumatic_Diagram").Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    End With

    OpenBook.Close
    
End If

'**** Check data***

Cells(1, 7) = 1

For iPnuematic = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For iProject = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(iPnuematic, 1) = Cells(iProject, 12) Then
            Cells(iPnuematic, 7) = 1
        End If
    Next iProject
Next iPnuematic

'*** Delete GN. project plan ***
 Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
 
'*** Clear Data ***
For iPnuematic = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(iPnuematic, 7) <> 1 Then
        Rows(iPnuematic).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next iPnuematic

'*** Delete mark 1 ***
 Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
 
    With Application
       .EnableEvents = True
       .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
       .ScreenUpdating = True
   End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want placing the processing result in the **initially active workbook**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try replacing this code part

```
'*** Delete define sheet name ***
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     If Sheet.Name = "Pnumatic_Diagram" Then
          Sheet.Delete
     End If
Next Sheet
```

with

```
'your existing code...
'*** Delete define sheet name ***
'create a workbook variable to be set as ActiveWorkbook
Dim wbAct As Workbook: set wbAct = ActiveWorkbook
For Each Sheet In wbAct.Worksheets
     If Sheet.Name = "Pnumatic_Diagram" Then
          Sheet.Delete
     End If
Next Sheet
'your existing code
```

Then replace `ThisWorkbook` with `wbAct`...

Like a general piece of advice, it is good to fully qualify all the used ranges. For instance `Sheets("Project plan").Range("B:B").Copy` works on the **active workbook**. To be sure that your code will not open another workbook, which will become the active one, you should use `wbAct.Sheets("Project plan").Range("B:B").Copy`.

And do the same for all cases where the code works on the active workbook, which may become problematic when the code becomes more complex: `Range("L:L")`, `Cells(1, 7)`, `Cells(iPnuematic, 1)` etc.